# Capturar alfanumericos que estan entre corchetes

Tags: php, regex

Dentro de archivos que tengan código PHP necesito encontrar texto alfanumérico que este entre corchetes y sin comillas(tanto simples como dobles) pero ignorando los valores enteros.

Tengo esta expresión regular **[([^'"$0123456789]]*)]** que encuentra lo que hay en negrita en el ejemplo que pongo a continuación:

**$str = $a[strings];**
$str2 = $b[strings1];
**$xxx[];**
$ZZZZ[7];
$ZZZZ['aaa'];
$ZZZZ["4"];

La expresión anterior encuentra todo lo que hay entre corchetes ignorando todo lo que tenga comillas(tanto simples como dobles) e ignora también lo que tenga números,
lo que necesito es que también encuentre **$str2 = $b[strings1];** pero ignorando este **$ZZZZ[7];**
si es posible que también ignore los corchetes que no tienen nada **$xxx[];** pero lo importante es que encuentre cadenas de texto que tengan números y letras o solo letras y que ignore las que tienen solo números

Todavía no he podido dar con esa expresión regular, si alguien me puede ayudar con ello le estaría muy agradecido.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

**Combina todas las cuerdas con corchetes:**

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

**Si desea cadenas sin corchetes:**

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**Alternativa, versión más lenta de coincidencia sin corchetes (usando "*" en lugar de "[^]"):**

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo necesito es para buscar en código PHP, es decir, en archivos que contengan código PHP, así como me lo describes no me sirvió cuando lo intente con el buscador de mi editor de código.

Comment: si te ha servido no te olvides de darle al check y la fecha para arriba asi puedes ayudar en la comunidad